# jQuery perform actions in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of jQuery that submits a form if any part of it is changed. The form is hidden by default on mobile. I'm trying to make it stay open when the page is reloaded.

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        // Submit results on change
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('#searchFilter input, #searchFilter select').on('change',function() {
                // if our filter is open on mobile
                if (jQuery('#toggle-filter').hasClass('open')) {
                    jQuery('#searchFilter').submit();
                    jQuery('#toggle-filter').addClass('open');
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('#searchFilter').submit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

It seems to be ignoring the `jQuery('#toggle-filter').addClass('open');` line.

Comment: When the page reloads the state of the HTML is reset. If you need to persist some changes between requests, then you need to store a state flag somewhere (cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage, server side etc) and then read that back on load and change the DOM appropriately

Comment: you do realize that you try to add a class it already has ?

Comment: thats absolutely right, i would prefer adding some flag from the serverside that only exists if form is submitted so you dont have to manage (persistent) flags clientside

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. I was thinking that the addClass method would change it, but I guess it won't run, because when the html loads, the javascript stops running.